# MobileFirst 7.1 Build Failed

Tags: ant, build, ibm-mobilefirst

The build process of a MobileFirst 7.1 project triggered by ANT is failing with this error message: /var/folders/5c/_7nw3_gd07931t2fjnqkqhcr0000gn/T/wlBuildResources/7.1.0.00.20160804-1930/environments/base/ios/buildinstructions.xml (No such file or directory)

It fails to build android version as well. I've checked the path in my OSX server and we had: /var/folders/5c/_7nw3_gd07931t2fjnqkqhcr0000gn/T/wlBuildResources/7.1.0.00.20160804-1930/environments

without /base/ios (or android) and without the xml file of course.

Any idea about the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the entirety of the wlBuildResources folde. This folder typically gets regenerated so perhaps the missing resource will be regenerated as well.